# My HTML is only outputting two columns I have 12

Tags: python, html

I want to output twelve columns of data to table but am only getting two I need to put a range in but dont know where in the bottom part of my code as I am only getting the first two columns and yes my first row is headers.

```
import csv
with open('bike_results.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in reader:
        print(','.join(row))
bike_list = list(reader)

sorted(bike_list)

html_content = "<html><body><table><tr><td>" + bike_list[0][0] + "</td><td>" + bike_list[0][1] + "</td></tr>"
i=1
while i < len(bike_list):
    html_content += "<tr><td>{}</td><td>{}</td></tr>".format(bike_list[i][0],bike_list[i][1])
    i+=1
html_content += "</table></body></html>"

import webbrowser

f = open('bike_results.html','w')

message = html_content
f.write(message)
f.close()

webbrowser.open_new_tab('bike_results.html')
```

Comment: why are you expecting 12 column ? you have provided 2 columns in your `html` code

Comment: Please post a sample of your input file. Otherwise it's hard for us to to tell why the code doesn't behave as you expect. And `sorted(bike_list)` does not do what you think it does. I think you mean `bike_list.sort()`.

Comment: I received the last part from another user and have found it returning 2 columns I would like to return 12 columns how do i adjust this?

Answer (score 0):

Just typing the extra fields ?

```
    import csv
    with open('bike_results.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
        for row in reader:
            print(','.join(row))
    bike_list = list(reader)

    sorted(bike_list)

    html_content = "<html><body><table><tr><td>" + bike_list[0][0] + "</td><td>" + bike_list[0][1] + "</td><td>" + bike_list[0][2] + "</td><td>" + bike_list[0][3] + "</td><td>" + bike_list[0][1] + "</td><td>" + bike_list[0][4] + "</td><td>" + bike_list[0][5] + "</td><td>" + bike_list[0][6] + "</td><td>" + bike_list[0][7] + "</td><td>" + bike_list[0][8] + "</td><td>" + bike_list[0][1] + "</td><td>" + bike_list[0][9] + "</td><td>" + bike_list[0][10] + "</td><td>" + bike_list[0][11] + "</td></tr>"
    i=1
    while i < len(bike_list):
        html_content += "<tr><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td></tr>".format(bike_list[i][0],bike_list[i][1],bike_list[i][2],bike_list[i][3],bike_list[i][4],bike_list[i][5],bike_list[i][6],bike_list[i][7],bike_list[i][8],bike_list[i][9],bike_list[i][10],bike_list[i][11])
        i+=1
    html_content += "</table></body></html>"

    import webbrowser

    f = open('bike_results.html','w')

    message = html_content
    f.write(message)
    f.close()

    webbrowser.open_new_tab('bike_results.html')
```